# Polynomial rings of two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Prove that $(x,y)$ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Here what is the definition of $(x,y)$? I don't know how to start the solution since I don't know the meaning of $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the [ideal generated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29#Ideal_generated_by_a_set) by $\{x,y\}$. Explicitly, $(x,y)$ consists of those polynomials whose constant term is zero.

Hint for the exercise: If $(x,y)=(g)$, then show that $g$ is a gcd of $x$ and $y$. But $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

Comment: So, can I define $(x,y)$ as follows?  $(x,y)=\{fx+gy|f,g\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]\}$

Comment: This is a consequence of the general definition, yes.